# Cannot install Xamarin.Forms UWP from MS App Center because of Visual C++ 2015 UWP runtime package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

After successful build I receive a link for downloading and installing UWP application (target and min framework v1809 b17763), but installation process hangs at 16% immediately after I see notification about installing `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 UWP runtime package`.

However, Windows Store shows that this package is currently not available.
If I deploy application from Visual Studio it gets installed and starts without any problems.

I would like to know why installer attempts to install `Visual C++` package.

Comment: You could ask for App Cener's support here: https://appcenter.ms/apps

Comment: We are having similar problems, but only on some devices.

Comment: @CMPalmer

Double Click the Certificate
Click "Install Certificate"
Tick "Local Machine" then click "Next"
Tick "Place all certificates in the following store" then click "Browse"
Click "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" and Click "Ok"
Click "Next" then "Finish"

Pay attention, it is "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" not User Certs.